# Kendo scheduler never calls the update method MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

The kendo scheduler has some options for events that can occur.

```
.Model(m =>
    {
        m.Id(f => f.TaskID);
        m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
        m.Field(f => f.OwnerID).DefaultValue(1);
        m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
        m.RecurrenceId(f => f.RecurrenceID);
    })
    .Read("Read", "Agenda")
    .Create("Create", "Agenda")
    .Destroy("Destroy", "Agenda")
    .Update("Update", "Agenda")
    .Filter(filters =>
    {
        filters.Add(model => model.OwnerID).IsEqualTo(1).Or().IsEqualTo(2);
    })
```

The Read method gives back my results from the database perfectly and when i try to insert a new event to the scheduler it calls for the Create method which inserts a new row in the table.

If there are existing events that i want to edit. I double click the event , change the information of it and press save.

[image]

I tried debugging the code with some breakpoints but the Update is never called. Instead it calls for the create method again.

I can however add the following to the Create method:

```
 public virtual JsonResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, EventModel task)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (task.ID == null)
            {
                // Create an event
                AllQueries.InsertEvent(task);
            }
            else
            {
                AllQueries.UpdateEvent(task);
            }
        }

        return Json(new[] { task }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

Without the check for the id to be equal to "Null" it keeps on adding every single request ever made so after adding 3 events it actually adds 6 new events.

This check works for the creation of new events but when i update an event it scans trough all exisitng events untill the id matches and when it is found it gets changed. This is no problem at the start but does become one when alot of events are added to the scheduler.

How do i get the Scheduler to call for my Update method on change instead of calling for the create method?

Comment: But if the ID is not null that means its a update right? else create.. I didnt get your this statement `but when i update an event it scans trough all exisitng events untill the id matches and when it is found it gets changed.`

Comment: if the task.ID is not equal to null it means it has an ID. when i debug the scheduler and go trough the steps 1 by 1 it goes trough all of the existing events in the database untill it finds the one with the same ID and then updates that specific event.

Comment: but that is what gonna happen even in your `Update` method too? right?

Comment: But how do i get it to evn run the update method instead of the Create since it is there for a reason i think but right now it is not called at all.

Comment: ya that is one issue we need to look into.. But still as a workaround you could still toggle between the logic of update and create.. thats what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID has to be non-capital. Once you change the primary key called ID to id everything works fine.